# Applying "%.1f" to multiple variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point-precision

Just started a course and the exercise was to learn how to use `round(x, n)` to truncate `floats`.

Only problem is, it didn't.  I found out about how to use `%.1f` online, but is there a way to apply it to multiple variables instead having to write it over and over?

I have it set up like below:

```
a = float(input("a:"))
b = float(input("b:"))
c = float(input("c:"))
d = float(input("d:"))
e = float(input("e:"))

sum = a + b + c + d + e
average = sum/5

print ("The sum of ", "%.1f" % (a), ", ", "%.1f" % (b), ",", "%.1f" % (c), ", ", "%.1f" % (d), ", and ", "%.1f" % (e), "is ", "%.1f" % (sum), ". Meanwhile, the average is ", "%.2f" % (average), ".")
```

Is there a way to apply the `%.1f` without having to write it so much?

edit: thanks to everyone that helped out.  I found onur güngör's to have worked best with what I'm looking for, but I learned a lot more than what I needed from everyone's input.  appreciate it.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this.

```
n = 10
vars = []
for i = range(1, n+1):
  vars.append(float(input("%d: " % i)))

vars_sum = sum(vars)
average = vars_sum/5

str = "The sum of "
for var in vars[:-1]:
  str += "%.1f, " % var
str += "and " + "%.1f" % vars[-1:][0] + " is %.1f." % vars_sum
str += " Meanwhile, the average is %.2f." % average
print(str)
```

Comment: Woah, that's still a little beyond me.  Can you explain what's going on please?

Comment: for var in vars[:-1]
  str += "%.1f, " % var
end part does the work, += operations add the strings back to back.

Comment: I get an "invalid syntax" when it reaches for var in vars[:-1].

Comment: Sorry I fixed the code. I was using Julia a lot recently :)

Comment: Woah, it finally worked.  Mind explaining what the "append" does?

Comment: Actually, if I wanted to have an input that defines "n" possible variables, how would I go about writing it?

Comment: I edited it again but this started to seem like an assisted homework session :) Will you choose an answer?

Comment: To be honest the homework assignment this was based on was to simply become familiar with round(x, n), but I didn't like how floats were showing the output, which is how I learned about %.1f.  The rest of this stuff (asking about how I could ask for "n" variables) was out of curiosity.  Thanks for all the help though!  How do I go about choosing an answer?

Comment: Right now you will have 4 answers when you view the question while you're logged in. You are expected to choose the answer which matches best to your question.

Comment: Hmmm, I edited my post saying that I liked your answer best.  Was that what I needed to do?

Comment: I don't recall exactly but there should be a button or a link near up and down arrows on the left of my answer. I guess it read "choose this as the answer" or something like that.

Comment: @ onur güngör  Figured it out.  It's the check mark near your name.  Thanks a bunch for answering all my questions!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do what you're trying to do directly.  But, you could try a double-format and use the newer style.

```
str = "values: {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}".format("{:.2f}");
str = str.format(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Comment: Do I put my variables a-e into the {}'s?

Comment: Then do I add more {}'s since I want to apply it to everything (a-e, sum, and average)?  I keep getting "tuple index out of range"

Comment: Yes, you'll need the same number of `{}`s and `val`s as you have variables you want to write out.

Comment: I've changed the example above to match what you're looking for

Comment: This only works if he does `"{} {} {}".format("{:.2f}", "{:.2f}", "{:.2f}")` which of course is useless.

Comment: Check out the "Reuse Same Variable Multiple Times" section here: https://mkaz.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/

Comment: I changed the `{}`s to `{0}`s to match the example on that page.  That may be the problem you're referring to.

Comment: @Quicksilver002 there we go :)

Answer (score 2):

You can conveniently store these values in a list. For example:

```
names = list("abcde")
values = [ float(input(n + ":")) for n in names ]
fvalues = ', '.join("{:.1f}".format(v) for v in values)
```

`fvalues` might then look like:

```
'4.0, 4.4, 4.4, 2.3, 4.4'
```

The values can also be computed upon in list form:

```
total = sum(values)
avg = total / len(values)
```

If you wished a more debugging-oriented formatting of the value list, something like:

```
dvalues = '  '.join("{}: {:.1f}".format(n,v) for n,v in zip(names,values))
```

Yields:

```
'a: 4.0  b: 4.4  c: 4.4  d: 2.3  e: 4.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's useful here to use string formatting. Build your formatter string, then apply it to multiple values.

```
one_digit_float = "{:.1f}"

responses = dict()
for varname in ['a','b','c','d','e']:
    responses[varname] = input(varname+": ")
# this is equivalent to:
# # responses = {varname: input(varname+": ") for varname in 'abcde'}
print "Variables are " + ', '.join(varname + ": " + one_digit_float.format(val) for varname,val in responses.items())
```